# HTML forms, add area on click

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, addition

I'm not sure how to ask what I'm looking for to search how-tos. I am building a form and one of the entries requires users to list an appliance, its voltage, watts, amps, phase, etc.

I'd like a simple row with "X" columns providing the text areas for one appliance and then the ability to click a link to 'add another appliance' using jquery/html.

I like using placeholder text to save space on the page. I can get all this set up just fine for a single entry like 'name' however I don't know how to implement an 'add entry' row. All of the data is stored via PHP in MySQL.

So A: What is the name of this type of form section. B: What is it called when we want to let the user add a row to this section?

I love making things harder than they really are. It's my specialty. I guess :)

EDIT: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_submit 
Using this format with 5 columns per entry (though it will all be on one line/row) I'd like to have an "add entry" link which generates a new blank entry option.

```
#elecNeeds input[type=text], textarea {
font-size: 12px;
font-style: italic; 
width: 15%;
height: 20px;
padding: 10px;  
color: #212323;
background: #E3E3E3;  
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
border: 2px #000 solid;
margin-bottom: 10px;
position: relative;
behavior: url(/js/PIE.htc);

    }

    <div id="elecNeeds">
    <input type="text" name="appliance" placeholder="Type of Equipment">
    <input type="text" name="voltage" placeholder="Voltage">
    <input type="text" name="watts" placeholder="Watts">
    <input type="text" name="amps" placeholder="Phase">
    <input type="text" name="notes" placeholder="Notes">
    <br />  Add an appliance
    </div>
```

Comment: can you show your sample code so we can see the format you would like it to look like?

Comment: At the moment I'm just setting up the html: "<input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="Contact First Name">"

Comment: I mean like the whole of your form like all of the html and pls edit your original question and put it in there.(pretty much show us what you got so far)

Comment: The format is simply a row that accepts text entries with about 5 columns for specifics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what's it called, but you probably want this - http://jsfiddle.net/uPWkf/1/

```
<form method="post" action="#" id="myForm">
    <div id="nameFields">
        <label>Watt <input type="text" name="watt0" /></label>
        <label>Volt <input type="text" name="volt0" /></label>
        <label>Amp <input type="text" name="amp0" /></label><br/><br />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" />
</form>
<a href="#" onclick="return false;" id="addRow">Add New Row</a>
```

and the JS

```
var i = 1;

$("#addRow").click(function() {
    $("#nameFields").append('<label>Watt <input type="text" name="watt' + i + '" /></label><label>Volt <input type="text" name="volt' + i + '" /></label><label>Amp <input type="text" name="amp' + i + '" /></label><br/><br />');

    i++;
});


$('#myForm').submit(function() {
    var values = $('#myForm').serialize();
    alert(values);
});
```

Comment: Hi Zoltan- You edited your code- I am working now off of the original and it seems to be doing the job so far...why did you edit? Thanks!

Comment: I have changed the way the added field names generated, so you'll have unique name for each input. And added an alert to show how the sent data will look like

Comment: Any idea why the spacing between the fields on the original is different from the others? Same css?  http://jsfiddle.net/Commandrea/MgJRd/1/

Comment: delete the `<label>`-s and put a whitespace between the inputs - http://jsfiddle.net/MgJRd/6/ :)

Comment: try to click Amps/Phase/Note in added row p.s. update by Zoltan fixed bug

Comment: @EgorSazanovich nothing weird happens to me. Any strange behavior on your side?

Comment: @ZoltanToth, in code from AAAndreAAA, click to fields after Watts will set focus to Watts field

Comment: @EgorSazanovich - Got it. Finally :) Good thing it's fixed already

Comment: Lovely! It's working like a charm. I didn't know that about white space in JS. Thank you for your help today- I learned quite a bit!

Comment: Hey guys- should I add a new ? or ask this here... I need to store these multiple entries in a MySQL database- that's all set up. Of course I can't store six appliance entries in one field/cell so am I supposed to just add the possible additional fields and values to the table? Like $POST_appliance, $POST_appliance1, etc. and if they don't get used, oh well? I'll be trying this soon; any better ideas would be great as I'm slammed w/ projects!

Comment: you should probably ask a new one :) But a quick answer - you should iterate through your `$_POST` array in a loop, checking each set for being empty, and if it's not - insert into the DB.

Answer (score 2):

I think You need to use `$(selector).append('<code>');` function. For example:

```
<a href="#" class="add">Add</a>
<table class="my_fuits">
    <tr>
        <td>Fruit</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="fuits[]" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and js(jQuery) code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // add one more row
    $(".add").live('click',function(){
        $(".my_fuits").append('<tr><td>Fruit '+$(".my_fruits input").length+'</td><td><input type="text" name="fuits[]" />[<a href="#" class="remove">X</a>]</td></tr>');
        return false;
    });

    //  remove row
    $(".remove").live('click',function(){
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
            return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I actually prefer this one, except that you forgot to add the class `.remove` to your link **X**, and I edited the count because it wasn't working. Now it's perfect: http://jsfiddle.net/U5XkP/1/ (You should update your code), but anyway, all credits to you for this, I like your method better.